# Conditionals for several CSS elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a CSS file that was originally embedded within a JavaScript file, so conditionals could be created by combining the CSS embedded style sheet with JavaScript logic. I am now in the process of separating the CSS and JavaScript files and have problems dealing with the larger chunks of CSS affected by a single conditional.

I know one solution is to create a conditional within the JavaScript/JQuery code that will handle the style changes:

```
if(condition == true) {
      $(".element").css("left", "360px");
}
```

That seems like an okay solution for CSS styles that have only a couple of changing attributes. However, in my case I would have to write 100~ lines of code just for the if else statement. Is there a more intuitive way to do this task?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of conditions you're checking for but is this an issue of screen size or ratio? If that's the case you want media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: I actually have to deal with the problem above within media query conditionals. I think the idea of adding classes to the element will solve my problem. Thanks for the reply, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could add a class to a parent like `<body>`

```
if(condition == true) {
      $('body').addClass('conditional-class');
}
```

And add specific rules in css:

```
.conditional-class .element{
   top: 360px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use objects to keep css, needed for some condition. For example:

```js
const firstCondition = {
  outline: '1px solid red',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  color: 'white'
};

const secondCondition = {
  outline: '1px solid blue',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
  color: 'yellow'
};

function applyStyles(node, styles){
  Object.keys(styles).forEach((key) => {
    node.style[key] = styles[key];
  });
}

let counter = 0;

const target = document.querySelector("#target");

function switchStyles(){
  if(counter % 2 === 0){
    applyStyles(target, firstCondition);
  }else if(counter % 2 === 1){
    applyStyles(target, secondCondition);
  }
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="target"> Hello! </div>
  
  <button onClick="switchStyles()">Switch style</button>
</div>
```

For further learning, I recommend you reading about [jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/jss)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a separate css file using javascript -

```
if(condition == true) {
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">');
} else {
  $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">');
}
```

short and simple, yet effective in your case.